# Creating n random lists

Tags: python, list, random, append, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to create n random 10-number-lists using python, and put these lists in a single variable(ran).

Below is my code:

```
from random import shuffle

def gen_random_list (num):
    ran = []
    k = [n for n in range(1, 11)]
    for i in range(num):
        shuffle(k)
        ran.append(k)
    return ran
```

The expected output should be something like:

```
[[4, 3, 10, 2, 8, 5, 7, 9, 6, 1],
[1, 3, 9, 6, 10, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7],
[4, 1, 3, 2, 9, 7, 8, 5, 6, 10]]
```

However, when I ran it in jupyter notebook, I got this:

```
[[4, 1, 3, 2, 9, 7, 8, 5, 6, 10],
[4, 1, 3, 2, 9, 7, 8, 5, 6, 10],
[4, 1, 3, 2, 9, 7, 8, 5, 6, 10]]
```

Which is just the repeatings of last random list. I've attached a **screenshot** of the output below.

[screenshot in jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9PKL.png)

Could someone tell me where the problem is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) is shuffling the list `l` in place. You have multiple instances of that same list in the list of lists so they all get shuffled at the same time.

To demonstrate, add a `print` in your loop:

```
def init_par (pop_size):
    ''' generate the 1st generation of parents
    pop_size should be an positive integer number'''
    if not (isinstance(pop_size, int) and pop_size>1):
        raise TypeError('bad operand type')
    else:
        par = []
        l=list(range(1,11))
        for i in range(pop_size):
            print i,l, par
            shuffle(l)
            par.append(l)
    return par
```

Prints:

```
0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] []
1 [9, 6, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 1, 8, 10] [[9, 6, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 1, 8, 10]]
2 [4, 5, 6, 2, 9, 3, 7, 8, 1, 10] [[4, 5, 6, 2, 9, 3, 7, 8, 1, 10], [4, 5, 6, 2, 9, 3, 7, 8, 1, 10]]
[[6, 8, 7, 1, 5, 4, 9, 3, 2, 10], [6, 8, 7, 1, 5, 4, 9, 3, 2, 10], [6, 8, 7, 1, 5, 4, 9, 3, 2, 10]]
```

Since each entry in `par` is just a view of the same list, when you shuffle one it *seems* to shuffle all of them.

To fix, make a new list each time through the loop:

```
def init_par (pop_size):
    ''' generate the 1st generation of parents
    pop_size should be an positive integer number'''
    if not (isinstance(pop_size, int) and pop_size>1):
        raise TypeError('bad operand type')
    else:
        par = []
        for i in range(pop_size):
            l=list(range(1,11)) # each one is a new list
            shuffle(l)
            par.append(l)
    return par
```

The *faster* way would be to use [sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) vs shuffle like so:

```
def init_par (pop_size):
    ''' generate the 1st generation of parents
    pop_size should be an positive integer number'''
    if not (isinstance(pop_size, int) and pop_size>1):
        raise TypeError('bad operand type')
    else:
        l=range(1,11)
        return [sample(l, k=len(l)) for _ in range(pop_size)]
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why the "append" only appends the last random list three times?

Comment: Shouldn't you change `[n for n in range(1, 11)]` to `list(range(1, 11))` and `l[:]` to `l.copy()` for simplicity? Or would that be a bad answer to a beginner?

Comment: @MegaIng: Great suggestion! Added.

Comment: @Dyckia: Because `l` is the same list the way you wrote the function. If you shuffle 1 `l` instance you shuffle them all.

Comment: @dawg Understood. Much appreciated!